# OOP - How to create a constructor in Reason

Tags: oop, ocaml, reason

Let's say I have two concrete factories:

```
class concreteFactory1 = {
  inherit abstractFactory;
  pub createProductA => (new productA1);
  pub createProductB => (new productB1);
};

class concreteFactory2 = {
  inherit abstractFactory;
  pub createProductA => (new productA2);
  pub createProductB => (new productB2);
};
```

I then would like to have another class that calls factory method(e.g. concreteFactory1#createProductA), based on factory passed into class. Something like the following (syntax is wrong, I know):

```
class testFactory factory => {
  as _;
  pub createProductA => Js.log factory#createProductA;
};
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome. Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing syntactically wrong with what you've written. But of course `Js.log` will return `unit`. You'll also need to specify what `factory` is: `(factory: abstractFactory)`.

Comment: You are right. In addition, just added the following in order to pass one class to another: https://github.com/CharlieGreenman/reason-oop-patterns/commit/86a59462181853cf5e1c344f730004f79a26af77